# How do I remove a rust stain from my granite counter top?

Tags: removal, stain

My wife had a towel holder on our granite bathroon counter top.  It left a rust stain on the counter.  What can I use to remove?

Comment: CLR did not work.  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

A product called CLR (Calcium, Lime & Rust remover) is really good at getting rust stains off tile, granite, concrete and toilets. It is available at most grocery stores in my area. make sure to rinse well after the stain vanishes (it works very quickly).